# Break up a long HTML string

Tags: html, notepad++

I made a URL call in Java to a small webpage. It returns a very long string of HTML code, including a jumble of tags.

It's very hard to read when it's all on one line.

I copied it into Notepad++ and I started manually breaking it up in terms of tags to be a little more comprehensive, but after a minute I realized there's gotta be a better way.

So my question is this; how do you break up a large line of HTML into its proper line-by-line formatting layout so a human can understand quickly what's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use something that already exists (if you're just trying to read the HTML). [freeformatter](http://www.freeformatter.com/html-formatter.html) for example